# TypeScript object Array type definition

Tags: arrays, typescript

What is the difference between this two type definitions?

```
type objectArray = [object]

type objectArray = object[]
```

Comment: The first is a tuple, second is array type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object]` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types). It's the type of an array with a single value in it, and the value must be an `object`.

`object[]` is the same as `Array<object>`. It's the type of an array with any number of values, where any such values must be `object`.

All tuples are arrays, but a tuple is a more restrictive type of array, with a specified number of elements.